# Dynamic active navigation

Tags: php, html, css, dynamic, navigation

I have created a header and navigation bar and am including it dynamically to all of my web pages using the php include statement:

```
<?php include "assets/includes/header.php";?>`
```

I have created an active class for the navbar to style the current active page and hover styling for the un-selected pages. However, because all of the navigation code is in the one header.php file, my active styling does not apply to all active pages, only the home page. I am wondering if it is possible to add active styling to only the current active pages dynamically? So only active styling on the active pages and the rest hover styling?I have searched far and wide for how this can be done but have not found a solution. Any help or suggestions would be most appreciated. Thanks!

```css
div {
  background:#eaebf0;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:150px;
}
ul li {
  list-style:none;
  margin-top:10px;
  padding:8px;
  margin-left:0px;
}

.active {
  background:#dfe0e5;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-left:2px solid #00f;
  padding:8px;
  
}
li:hover:not(.active){
background-color:lightblue;
padding:8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active six"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="one"> <a href="#">About </a></li>
    <li class="one"> <a href="#">photos</a> </li>
    <li class="one"><a href="#"> vedios</a> </li>
    <li class="one"> <a href="#">likes</a> </li>
    <li class="one"> <a href="#">posts</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to check the current script filename in php and see if it matches a menu item, and highlight that menu item if it does (by echoing the active class string into the relevant element).  But right now your links don't seem to point to php files

Comment: `href="#"` is never going to load a different page. How are you loading these resources?

Comment: I've done this historically by outputting URL to JS variable then iterating over all links in my menu and checking for `href` match between current URL and menu item. On match add `active` class, else remove `active` class.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the helpful comments. Yeah, have seen this done with both javascript and php but decided php was a good solution. As ADyson advised, i had to echo the active class string into the relevant element using a basename() function to return the filename from a path as suggested:

```
     <li class="six">  <a href="index.php" class="<?php  

if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])=="index.php"){echo "active";
      }else{
        echo "";

  } ?>">Home</a></li>
```

Would be interested in any solutions with javascript too and will research this further